# Hightlight a Bar in HighCharts Bar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bar-chart

How can I make a bar standout in a  bar chart made in Highchart.js ?

Suppose I have a bar chart of success , fails , warnings (all in one array), and success score is too high , it dwarfs the error bar and is not easily visual. I want to make 'error bar' standout if value > 0.

```
              RenderBarChart('service_stats'+x, [
                                            {y:1000, color: 'green', url:'http://www.google.com'},
                                            {y:5, color: 'red', url:'http://www.googl22e.com'},
                                            {y:6, color: 'orange', url:'http://www.googl22e.com'},
                                            {y:7, color: 'yello', url:'http://www.googl22e.com'},
                                            ], 'servidsace_stats');


    function RenderBarChart(elementId, dataList, name) {
            new Highcharts.Chart({

                      chart: {
                          renderTo: elementId,
                          plotBackgroundColor: null,
                          plotBorderWidth: null,
                          plotShadow: true
                      },


        title: {
            text: 'Host Statistics'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Cluster: Appservers'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['OK', 'CRITICAL', 'WARNING', 'UNKNOWN'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null,
            },
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 100,
            y: 100,
            floating: false,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            shadow: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series:[{
                        type: 'bar',
                        name: name,
                        data: dataList,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                         point: {
                                events: {
                                click: function() {
                                location.href = this.options.url;
                    }
                }
            }
                     }]
                 }
```

Increasing the width of error bar does not help. Scaling the height might help but  couldn't do it.

Comment: Something like this http://www.highcharts.com/demo/error-bar ? Have you any mockup of your chart?

Comment: @sebastian No that does not help . I just want to highlight the bar . Not add something to it.

Comment: Can you rephrase? It sounds like you're saying if the 'score' value is too high [each success is +1 score?], that bar should be highlighted... But you have one data array - `dataList` that holds all successes, fails and warnings?

Comment: much easier to help with live demo

Comment: @jlbriggs - http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/195/ .. Consider "0" (value=1100) bar shows all hosts that are fine. and "1" Bar shows all hosts that are Down or have error. Since value of "1" bar is often small it is dwarfed by OK bar (and not easily visible on dashboard screen compared to OK bar) though "1" bar is very critical. Is there a way I can get this "Error/"1" Bar in the bar chart to get some special highlighting if value > 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things you can do.

Here is one `example fiddle`, using a couple of different techniques to highlight the bar:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/78LHt/

1) you can specify colors in the data point object. You'll need to pre-process your data to build the appropriate data point depending on the specifics

2) you can add data labels to points you need to highlight

**However** - I would strongly caution that this type of display is essentially useless for this purpose.
Unless you have serious problems going on, as you've seen, the comparison is not remotely helpful, and in fact obscures exactly the one piece of information that you need to be aware of.

This is one of the cases where a simple table with numbers listed will be far more effective at displaying the type of data that you need.

something simple and clear. exampe:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/ZHw2a/

To bring charts back into, a sparkline of the status history would be useful:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/m96rk/